# Is the element in the connected component?

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, algebraic-groups, centralisers

I posted this question at stack exchange, got two upvotes but no answer. If it doesn't belong here, please let me know.

In the algebraic group $G$ = PGL$_{8}$($\mathbb{C}$), there are two involutions $a =$  $\Delta$
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}_{4}$ and $b =$  $\begin{pmatrix}
-I_{2} & 0\\
0 & I_{6}\\
\end{pmatrix}$ and the Klein four group generated by them have a centraliser in $G$, the connected component of which is $A_{2}A_{2}T_{3}$.

I'm aware that $c =$  $\Delta$
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}_{4}$ centralises both $a$ and $b$. How to see if $c$ is in this connected component?

Here $\Delta (M)_{i}$ means $i$ copies of $M$ embedded diagonally. Thank you!